# type '() => Map<String, dynamic>?' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

can I have some help regarding this error? Here is the attachment of the code and error issue

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your StreamBuilder type is not nullable, the actual return type it is.

Answer (score 1):

`Map<String, dynamic>?` is nullable, while `Map<String, dynamic>` is not nullable, therefore the former is not a subtype of the latter and the error message is expected. You will need to make sure that either both are nullable or none of them are nullable.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `snapshot.data.data` is actually a method thata you can call to get the data, that means, `snapshot.data.data()` gives you `Map<String, dynamic>?`, since it is possible to have a `DocumentSnapshot` that doesn't exist and thus has no (data) fields.

This leads to having two types in play here:

- `Map<String, dynamic>` is a map of string keys and values of an unknown type.
- `Map<String, dynamic>?` can either be a map or be `null`, in your `snapshot.data.data`.

You can't assign a value of the second type to a variable of the first type, as such a variable has no way to store the `null` value.

So you must either make the variable nullable too, by making it of type `Map<String, dynamic>?`, or (and usually better) you can assert in your code that the value is not `null` before assigning it to the variable.

The latter would look something like:

```dart
if (snapshot.data.data != null) {
  userProfile.setData(snapshot.data.data()!);
}
```